# Repackaging android app for blackberry playbook, BarGenerator error

Tags: android, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to repackage my app for blackberry using the Eclipse plugin, and when trying to run it in my simulator I get this error:

```
D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse>set version=1.0.2 

D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse>set LIB=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7 win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\234\1\.cp\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin\\..\lib 

D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse>java -Xmx512M -cp "D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\234\1\.cp\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin\\..\lib\BARPackager.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\234\1\.cp\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin\\..\lib\Apk2Bar-1.0.2.jar" net.rim.tools.apk2bar.Apk2bar "C:\Users\Simon\workspace\BB_app\bin\BB_app.apk" "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\\" -t "C:\Users\Simon\workspace\BB_app\bin\classes" -d "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\simdebugtoken.bar" 
[BarGenerator] 
[BarGenerator] Start packaging BB_app.apk
[ERROR] [BarGenerator] zip file is empty
[BarGenerator] BB_app.apk ................................... failed
[BarGenerator] Summary: Total Apk files # 1; succeeded: 0; skipped: 0; failed: 1
```

I've searched here and elsewhere but I can't find anything about "zip file is empty". 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to .zip your .apk file >BB_app.zip instead of BB_app.apk

Comment: Actually it was some kind of an Eclipse error. I reinstalled it and it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Eclipse error. Reinstalled it and everything went fine.